# Why does Andy drink the shots in the “Cross Hands” pub?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-worlds-end

I was wondering about a scene in *The World's End*. Why did Andy drink those shots in the “Cross Hands” Pub since he's supposed to be teetotal?

I have my theories but feel free to post your own.

1. He feels pressured by the fact that the others want him to drive.
2. He's craving for alcohol ;) (come on 16 years!?)
3. He prefers Steven's plan
4. He secretly likes a waitress in "The Good Companion"
5. Just because the plot needs him to...
6. Let's BooBoo

Comment: *"He prefers Steven's plan"*  By 'Steven' DYM 'Gary' (the instigator of the pub crawl)?  I think it was a combination of 1 and 2, as well as *caving into the pressure* of following Gary and his plan..

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you changed the title back to the unexplanative version or was this just a site caching problem?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson  Huh.. I just realized while looking at the edit history, that I made a totally unintended edit to the first paragraph!  Thanks for correcting that.  (And I agree your title was much better..)

Comment: I hadn't considered a combination of 2 reasons, that's a good point :)

Comment: By the way, what does DYM mean   ? (English is not my first language)

Comment: English **is** my first language, but *Australian English* is not :D A little help there @AndrewThompson.

Comment: Help where lol, I don't see a link or anything  (?) but I searched on the internet and it seems that "DYM" means "do you mind" Am I correct ?

Comment: I meant it as 'do you mean..?'.  My apologies for the confusion.  :P

Answer (score 3):

It's been a bit since I've seen the movie, but I don't recall Andy drinking anything until after the aliens/robots/what have you showed up.  So, I think was a "welp, there's something weird going down, might as well have a drink... or 6"